# Optimize the query to improve the performance

Tags: sql, query-optimization, query-performance, database-cursor

```
DECLARE @userId INT  

DECLARE newCur CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT DISTINCT USER 
     FROM User_Table  --Count 3497    

OPEN newCur    

FETCH NEXT FROM newCur INTO @userId  

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)    
BEGIN    
    EXEC sp_Updatedept @userId   
    SET @userId = ''  

    FETCH NEXT FROM newCur INTO @userId  
END    

CLOSE newCur 
DEALLOCATE newCur
```

This query runs for 3 hours and can extend based on the increase in table records.

As it's using a cursor, it is very slow and hampers the performance; I need to optimize the query so it can run in 30 minutes or less.

Any suggestion or help with query is much appreciated.

Comment: Such is the downside to using stored procedures and cursors.  Set-based operations are usually much faster.

Comment: Can you provide some example for the above script.

Comment: . . . It is not clear what `sp_Updatedept` does.

Comment: Can anyone advise on this ?